# Google Charts - Adding trend line option breaks chart

Tags: google-visualization

Trying to add a trend line to a line chart in Google Charts but every time I add the trend line option the chart will not display. My understanding is that the "date" column type is a continuous axis so I don't understand why it won't add the trend line.

```html
 var data4 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data4.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data4.addColumn('number', 'Average Price');

        data4.addRows([
          [new Date('12/19/2017'), 10.75],[new Date('12/20/2017'), 6.30],[new Date('12/21/2017'), 8.00],[new Date('12/22/2017'), 9.21],[new Date('12/24/2017'), 5.68]         ]);
       
          var options = {
           hAxis: {
             title: 'Day'
           },
           vAxis: {
             title: 'Average Price'
           }
              trendlines: { 0: {} }
       };


        var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));

        chart4.draw(data4, options);
```

Comment: Better indenting code would make it easier to understand.

Comment: you need a comma before `trendlines` -- after `vAxis`

Comment: Argh, thank you. I stared at it for two days without seeing that.